# How can I upload file in CakePHP 2.0.4

Tags: amazon-s3, cakephp-2.0

I tried 2-3 plug-ins in order to use upload function. I want to upload photos to S3. I couldn't do it with any of them. Which plug-in is the best one for version 2.0.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there aren't any plugins that have been updated for 2.0, I would recommend updating one yourself or using the [amazon-s3-php-class](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class) on GitHub. It's an active project and would require to you place the class in your **Vendors** directory.

To import:

```
App::import(‘vendor’, ‘S3’);
```

To instantiate with your config:

```
$S3 = new S3($accessKey, $secretKey);
```

Comment: @Burak it had an update yesterday, so I'm surprised it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I thing that the best solution is this plugin
http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader#transfering-files-to-amazon-s3
I use it since 2 years for every cake project, it works like a charm, easy to configure and powerful

Answer (score -1):

Folder Place in given location for example: `project-folder/vendors`.

To Import:

```
function uploadToS3()
    {
      if(!empty($this->request->data))
      {
        $data = $this->request->data;

        // Import Vendor
        App::import('Vendor', '/s3/S3');

        //AWS access info
        if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) 
           define('awsAccessKey', 'Change Here');

        if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) 
           define('awsSecretKey', 'Change Here');

        //instantiate the class
        $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

        $s3->putObjectFile($data[$model]['file']['tmp_name'], "bucket", 
                           'destination'.$data[$model]['file']['name'],
                           S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

      }
    }
```